# Messed up my JavaScript return statements

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, return

I have a function defined like this:

```
  var getPhoneNumber = function (list, phoneType) {
    if (_.isEmpty(list)) {
      return "Not Entered"
    };
    _.each(list, function(phoneNo){

      if (phoneNo.name === phoneType) {
        return phoneNo.value;
      };
    });
    return "Not Entered";
  }
```

`list` is an `Array`, while `phoneType` is a `String`. The problem is the function always returns the value `Not Entered` even if the `list` is not empty and has a `phoneNo.name` equal to `phoneType`. If I add a `console.log` in the `if` it shows that the condition is true and prints the `console.log` message but still returns `Not Entered`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return phoneNo.value;` doesn't correspond to the function `getPhoneNumber`, but to the function passes as callback at `_.each`.

You should try something like this instead:

```
var getPhoneNumber = function (list, phoneType) {
    var value = null;
    _.each(list, function(phoneNo){

      if (phoneNo.name === phoneType) {
        value = phoneNo.value;
      }
    });

    if(value !== null)
        return value;
    else
        return "Not Entered";
  }
```

Comment: This worked. However, I'd like to know where can the returned value of the callback be caught?

Comment: I don't think you can catch them, as the function can return a value at each iteration.

Comment: Oh alright, Thanks for the help :) I spent more than an hour over this.